# WinHttp doesn't download from Amazon S3 on WinXP

Tags: visual-c++, ssl, amazon-s3, winhttp

Recently Amazon has disabled support of SSL for S3 buckets and it seems it causes problems on Win XP SP3.
I use this code

```
hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"MySession",
                    WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
                    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
                    WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);


if (bHTTPS)
{
  DWORD flags = WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE_PROTOCOL_TLS1;
  WinHttpSetOption(hSession, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURE_PROTOCOLS, &flags, sizeof(flags));
}

port = bHTTPS ? INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT : INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT;
hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, srv_w, port, 0);    
hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, vrb_w, adr_w, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, NULL,  WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH | (bHTTPS ? WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE : 0));

if (bHTTPS)
{
  DWORD dwSecFlag = SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID | 
                        SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID | 
                        SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_UNKNOWN_CA | 
                        SECURITY_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_WRONG_USAGE;

  WinHttpSetOption(hRequest, WINHTTP_OPTION_SECURITY_FLAGS, &dwSecFlag, sizeof(dwSecFlag));
}

WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, hdr_w, (headers != NULL) ? -1 : 0, data, size, size, 0);
WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
```

This works on Win7 and worked a month or so ago on WinXP. But now I get WinHttp error 12152: The server returned an invalid or unrecognized response. I have enabled tracing and log fiel has a different error:

```
17:47:47.057 ::*0000001* :: WinHttpSendRequest(0x10a0000, "", 0, 0x0, 0, 0, 0)
17:47:47.135 ::*0000001* :: "s3.amazonaws.com" resolved
17:47:47.307 ::*0000001* :: Winsock/RPC/SSL/Transport error: 0x90312 [SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED]
```

Is there a way to fix this problem without using 3rd party libraries? (browsers, including IE, download files without problems).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having the same issue. I think it may be caused by a problem with the SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA cipher that is chosen in WinHTTP on XP. Try this as a test:
On the XP machine, add a new DWORD value called "Enabled" to the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers\Triple DES 168/168
```

This disables that cipher and seems to fix the issue for me. This is not an ideal solution however, and I'm still not sure of the underlying issue. Perhaps a problem with whatever crypto provider Amazon is using?

Comment: i'm accepting your solution for now, it does fix the problem, but i'm not sure that disabling protocols on end-user PC's is a good idea :) maybe later someone suggest a better way or explains the underlying problem.

Comment: Yes, 0! Sorry about the omission. I agree that this isn't a feasible solution, I'm still trying to figure out exactly what's causing that cipher to make the connection handshake fail.

Comment: I have posted the WinInet code that works without registry fix

Answer (score 0):

I was able to redo the code and use WinInet which works fine.

```
hInternet = InternetOpen("myapp", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
hConnect = InternetConnect(hInternet, server, port, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);

const char *accept_types[] = { "*/*", NULL };
DWORD flags = INTERNET_FLAG_NO_UI | INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE;

hRequest = HttpOpenRequest(hConnect, verb, addr, NULL, NULL, accept_types, flags, NULL);
bResults = HttpSendRequest(hRequest, headers, -1, data, size);

bResults = HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE, tmp_buf, &buf_sz, NULL);
// check for 200 here...

bResults = HttpQueryInfo(hRequest, HTTP_QUERY_CONTENT_LENGTH, tmp_buf, &buf_sz, NULL);
// allocate a buffer here

INTERNET_BUFFERS buf = { sizeof(INTERNET_BUFFERS) };
buf.lpvBuffer = &buffer[0];
buf.dwBufferTotal = content_length;

// read using InternetReadFileEx or InternetReadFile
```

the code doesn't have explicit TLS declaration, but if server supports only TLS the client won't have any choice.

Comment: I am seeing this occur with only WinHTTP - not WinInet. IE 8 (installed on the XP machine) also works fine, but I think it uses WinInet on its back end.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you keep your unsafe `dwFlags` you could turn off HTTPS.
You are totaly ignoring any SSL errors and allowing a lot of attacks and content manipulation.

So if you don't care about security why use HTTPS?

*Just a sidenote:*
you should care about security and remove these unsafe flags.

Comment: ok, I remove those flags, the code still doesn't work on win XP. let's hear some secure hints.